# FIWARE entity as a group of KPI attributes

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion

[Our system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67470035/fiware-context-provider-hello-world-not-working) needs to return several KPIs grouped in different *topics*:

- Census:

  - citizens (number of inhabitants)
  - citizens without any studies
  - ...
- Information desk

  - Phone response time
  - Mail response time
  - ...
- Tax

  - Online payments
  - Window payments
  - ...

To my understanding, **it would make sense to have an entity for each *topic* and each KPI being a *KeyPerformanceIndicator* attribute**. eg: This could work similar to:

```json
{
    "description": "Census Information system",
    "dataProvided": {
        "entities": [
            {
                "idPattern": ".*"
            }
        ],
        "attrs":[    //THIS SEEMS AN INTERESTING APPROACH, BUT SADLY ALSO INVALID
            {
                "name": "citizens",
                "type": "KeyPerformanceIndicator"
            },
            {
                "name": "citizens_without_studies",
                "type": "KeyPerformanceIndicator"
            },
            //...
        ]
    },
    "provider": {
        "http": {
            "url": "http://myhost/v2/census"
        }
    }
}
```

(TL;DR: "attrs" supports strings only, so can't return *complex/data modeled* types, like [KPI](https://github.com/smart-data-models/dataModel.KeyPerformanceIndicator/blob/master/keyPerformanceIndicator/README.md))

Setting this *happy idea* aside, **what it would be a good approach to solve this?**

Must each KPI be an entity?

Is NGSI-LD what I'm looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your case can be solved in NGIv2. Let my try to explain.

**Must each KPI be an entity?**

Yes. That's the usual way of modelling KPIs according to the [KPIs datamodel](https://github.com/smart-data-models/dataModel.KeyPerformanceIndicator/blob/master/keyPerformanceIndicator/doc/spec.md). Each KPI is modeled as an entity of type `KeyPerformanceIndicator`.

**Can KPIs be categorized?**

Yes. You can use the `category` attribute to do that.

For instance, you can have an KPI "Online payments" of category "Tax Information" modeled this way:

```
{  
  "id": "OnlinePayments",  
  "type": "KeyPerformanceIndicator",  
  ...
  "category": ["taxInformation"],  
  ...
}
```

Note that `category` is an array, so a given KPI could belong to more than one category  (although in your use case it seems that each KPI belongs to exactly one category so you don't need this feature)

**How can I get KPIs that belong to a given category?**

You can use regular Orion Context Broker filtering features for that. For instance, to get all KPIs in category `taxInformation` you could use this key:

```
GET /v2/entitites?type=KeyPerformanceIndicator&q=category:taxInformation
```

or this expression in subscriptions:

```
{
    "subject": {
        "entities": [
            {
                "idPattern": ".*",
                "type": "KeyPerformanceIndicator"
            }
        ],
        "condition": {
            ...
            "expression": {
               "q": "category:taxInformation"
            }
         }
    },
    ...
}
```

Comment: [If query filtering were usable with Context Providers...](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion/issues/2282)

Comment: @fgalan wouldn't it make sense to group kpi's using fiware-service?

Comment: @Perrolobo CPs were mentioned on the first 2 words of my message ;).
On the other hand, Context provides are supposed to be providers of context, so I disagree with your statement.

Comment: fiware-service is typically used to provide context isolation among clients/project/tenants. E.g. `fiware-service: murcia` for the KPIs of the Murcia city and `fiware-service: cartagena` for the KPIs of the Cartagena city (each fiware-service which it's own authorized users). But of course, this possiblity could also be explored, in the case `category` solution don't suffice your case.

Comment: wouldn't that be servicepath?.
category does not work, as query filtering is not working with CP.

Mantaining KeyPerfromanceIndicator type as _contract_ + CP only accepting .* pattern implies every CP system would receive every request...so wondering if fiware-service was a valid solution to isolate providers

Answer (score 0):

If what you are trying to accomplish is to offer an NGSI interface for your KPI data, you can just create your own adaptor on top of your database that offers a REST interface compliant with NGSI-LD and such service can just return entities of type `KeyPerformanceIndicator`. Then, you can federate it to a Context Broker with a simple registration i.e. for entities of type `KeyPerformanceIndicator`. And that's all.

The usage of Linked Data would be recommendable as well, so I would go for NGSI-LD, as it has been officially endorsed by ETSI.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on CONTEXT ADAPTERS vs CONTEXT PROVIDERS? Any docs or link would be much appreciated

Comment: It is just the same, that is just a matter of terminology. The main takeaway is that you can just create a REST API following the the NGSI specification and the `KeyPerformanceIndicator` Data Model, on top of your database.

Comment: +1.
dealing with some technical issues now, but the scenario is clear. thanks!